# MVC Custom Authorization stops automatically after some time on live server

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, authentication, authorization, asp.net-identity

I have created asp .net mvc website and created custom authentication and authorization feature. This feature works for some time but stops working after certain amount of time. Can someone please help.

There is no error users are simply able to access restricted area.

My Custom code:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class, AllowMultiple = true, Inherited = true)]
    public class CustomAuthrizationPayment : AuthorizeAttribute
    {
        bool authorize = false;
        bool IsLoggedIn = false;
        protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
        {

            string currentUserId = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(currentUserId))
            {
                using (IACLBEntities context = new IACLBEntities())
                {
                    var userStatus = context.AspNetUsers.FirstOrDefault(r => r.Email == currentUserId).IsActive;
                    if (userStatus != null)
                    {
                        authorize = (bool)userStatus;
                        IsLoggedIn = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        authorize = false;
                    }
                }
            }

            return authorize;
        }
        protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
        {
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
            if (IsLoggedIn == false)//----- Return To Login page
            {
                filterContext.Result = new HttpUnauthorizedResult();
            }
            else
            {
                filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(
                                   new RouteValueDictionary
                                   {
                                       { "action", "Index" },
                                       { "controller", "Payment" },
                                       {"area","" }
                                   });

            }
        }
    }
```

How I am applying to controller:

```
 [CustomAuthrizationPayment()]
    public class CorporateRefrencesController : Controller
    {
```

Comment: Can you also attach the HTTP request please

Comment: How? Where to find?